# Sql Server - Using id of updated row as argument in delete statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Action_Voided on Action
    AFTER UPDATE AS
    BEGIN
        IF UPDATE (voided)
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM User_Actions where action_id = ? -- here I need to get the Id of Action that was updated on voided column
            END
    END:
```

and I need to get hold on Id of a row that was updated by this trigger, and use this Id as an argument of delete statement.
I was doing some research but can't figure how to use inserted/deleted tables combination to make this work.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Are you talking about inserted/deleted magic tables? Check these links out http://www.mindstick.com/Blog/211/Magic%20Table%20in%20SQL%20Server  and http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/7OT8250912-Inserted,-Deleted-Logical-table-in-SQL-Server.html

Comment: Second link is probably good lead, thank you.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought the first 1 would be of use. Anyways is it as good as an acceptable answer to you? If yes then I will convert it as an answer and you can mark it as acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure if this will solve your problem but if you want to get the "id" column of a row which is getting updated, then you can use the `inserted` magic table here. The following should be the modified trigger for you. I have not tested it so please pardon my syntax errors if any. If any then let me know I will modify my answer accordingly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Action_Voided on Action
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE (voided)
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM User_Actions 
            where action_id IN (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED)
        END
END:
```

Hope this helps.